# Post batch request with Breezejs

Tags: odata, breeze, asp.net-web-api

I've been trying to POST an entity using Breezejs and WebAPI OData Controllers.

Here are the configurations:

```
config.Routes.MapODataRoute(
routeName: "odata",
routePrefix: "odata",
model: model,
batchHandler: new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
```

Where the model is very straight forward:

```
public class ServiceMetadata
{
    public int ServiceMetadataId { get; set; }
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ObjectState? State { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

And it is mapped through the default:

```
ODataModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
```

**The Client** is also very simple taken using AngularJs and partially from the Todo example: http://www.breezejs.com/samples/todo-angular

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);
var serviceName = 'http://localhost:8081/odata/';
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "OData" });
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
manager.enableSaveQueuing(true);
```

The actual Posting is done using the default createEntity() method:

```
function createServiceMetadata(initialValues) {
    return manager.createEntity('ServiceMetadata', initialValues);
}
```

And the whole thing looks like:

```
 serviceMetadatas.createServiceMetadata({
     ServiceName: $scope.newServiceName,
     Description: $scope.newServiceDescription
 });

 serviceMetadatas.saveChanges();
```

However, the request is not being transferred to the correct controller (ServiceMetadatasController which inherits from EntitySetController), or any other controller for that matter.

The HTTP request looks like this:

```
    POST http://localhost:8081/odata/$batch HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0
Accept: multipart/mixed
Accept-Language: he-IL,he;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; charset=UTF-8;boundary=batch_4f09-d7cf-dd99
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0
Referer: http://localhost:9000/
Content-Length: 580
Origin: http://localhost:9000
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache


--batch_4f09-d7cf-dd99
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_ca0c-06b7-ddbe

--changeset_ca0c-06b7-ddbe
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST ServiceMetadatas HTTP/1.1
Content-ID: 1
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
Accept: application/atomsvc+xml;q=0.8, application/json;odata=verbose;q=0.5, */*;q=0.1
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0

{"ServiceMetadataId":-1,"ServiceName":"sdf sdf","Description":"sd fgs df","LastUpdated":null}
--changeset_ca0c-06b7-ddbe--

--batch_4f09-d7cf-dd99--
```

And the response:

```
    HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batchresponse_966d4460-e00e-4900-b1c9-85b17081cfac
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9000
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcVG9tZXJcRG9jdW1lbnRzXFZpc3VhbCBTdHVkaW8gMjAxMlxQcm9qZWN0c1xFYXN5Qml6eVxFYXN5Qml6eS5XZWJBUElcb2RhdGFcJGJhdGNo?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 15 Sep 2013 14:32:39 GMT
Content-Length: 443

--batchresponse_966d4460-e00e-4900-b1c9-85b17081cfac
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changesetresponse_44da5dcf-877d-4041-a82b-c51d06a4e9a4

--changesetresponse_44da5dcf-877d-4041-a82b-c51d06a4e9a4
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Content-ID: 1


--changesetresponse_44da5dcf-877d-4041-a82b-c51d06a4e9a4--
--batchresponse_966d4460-e00e-4900-b1c9-85b17081cfac--
```

Any idea what the hack is going on?
B.T.W GET requests works great.

P.S.
After looking at couple of demos, I though the using BreezeJS will be straight forward considering WebApi and OData.
I must say it is **Far** from being easy to configure this JS library. I hope it will turn out to be hard-to-setup but easy-to-use.

Thanks.

**@UPDATE** See **Javier**'s great answer!!

In after digging allllot on the breeze code, I came to realize that the problem is laying deep in the createChangeRequests() of breezejs, right here:

```
request.requestUri = entity.entityType.defaultResourceName;
```

Where for some reason the defaultResouceName, completely ignores the path to this entity.
Long story short, the following is a hack to resolve:

```
manager.metadataStore.getEntityType(ENTITY_TYPE).setProperties({defaultResourceName: THE_MISSING_PART_FROM_THE_URL + ENTITY_TYPE});
manager.createEntity(ENTITY_TYPE, values);
```

Not very nice, but still works!

Comment: Few notes - it looks like you are trying to post data of type X while the server is expecting type Y.  As far as configuration, think of how much more difficult it would be to create and set up your own data library.

Comment: How do you conclude the types are different? Thanks!

Comment: http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/operations/ check out the section describing why you get a 406

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't really help.

Comment: The problem appears to be that OData forces you to get the content type right, or it throws a 406.  If you are saying your content is of type whatever but the server accepts a different data type it will throw a 406.  I have not used OData before but I would guess you are either using the wrong adapter in Breeze or setting up your OData controller to accept the wrong content type.

Comment: Breeze is forcing me (I didn't find a way to change it) to send a batch request which the server doesn't like (probably the multipart/mixed). If I send a simple POST (through fiddler for ex.) having the same data it works perfectly.
I didn't even manage to force breeze to send a JSON (rather then sending the multipart).
This is probably because breeze asks for the metadata first and builds the model out of it. Either way, something is wrong with it.

Comment: Hi, it would be really helpful if you could provide a repro project so that I can check exactly what's going on.

Comment: There you go:
https://github.com/TomerAvni/ODataBatch
These is as-simple-as-it-gets project. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I've figured out the problem, see the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the url of the inner request. The url needs to be relative to the host. Let's say your service is hosted in `host/service` (in our case, service will be the equivalent as the odata prefix), so normally you send requests like `host/service/Customers` or `/service/Customers`.

When you issue a batch request, the urls in the inner requests might be absolute or relative to the host. The problem is that in your request, the url is `ServiceMetadatas` which is relative to the service root, not the host.

Web API is interpreting the relative url as `host/ServiceMetadatas` instead of as `host/service/ServiceMetadatas` and that's what causes the error.

Based on your repro project, the following request works fine:

```
POST http://localhost:6974/odata/$batch HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:6974
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0
Accept: multipart/mixed
Accept-Language: he-IL,he;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; charset=UTF-8;boundary=batch_4f09-d7cf-dd99
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0
Referer: http://localhost:9000/
Content-Length: 565
Origin: http://localhost:9000
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

--batch_4f09-d7cf-dd99
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_ca0c-06b7-ddbe

--changeset_ca0c-06b7-ddbe
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST odata/ServiceMetadatas HTTP/1.1
Content-ID: 1
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
Accept: application/atomsvc+xml;q=0.8, application/json;odata=verbose;q=0.5, */*;q=0.1
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0

{"ServiceMetadataId":-1,"ServiceName":"sdf sdf","Description":"sd fgs df"}
--changeset_ca0c-06b7-ddbe--

--batch_4f09-d7cf-dd99--
```

The associated response is the following one:

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batchresponse_6779b5e5-6e40-4363-9a98-5a33d062da28
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcamFjYWx2YXJcRG93bmxvYWRzXE9EYXRhQmF0Y2gtbWFzdGVyXENsZWFuV2ViQXBpUHJvamVjdFxvZGF0YVwkYmF0Y2g=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 17 Sep 2013 16:48:50 GMT
Content-Length: 872

--batchresponse_6779b5e5-6e40-4363-9a98-5a33d062da28
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changesetresponse_b63ca946-ce66-43e6-a78f-d44a5b8f2d5c

--changesetresponse_b63ca946-ce66-43e6-a78f-d44a5b8f2d5c
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Location: http://localhost:6974/odata/ServiceMetadatas(-1)
Content-ID: 1
Content-Type: application/json; odata=verbose; charset=utf-8
DataServiceVersion: 2.0

{
  "d":{
    "__metadata":{
      "id":"http://localhost:6974/odata/ServiceMetadatas(-1)","uri":"http://localhost:6974/odata/ServiceMetadatas(-1)","type":"CleanWebApiProject.Models.ServiceMetadata"
    },"ServiceMetadataId":-1,"ServiceName":"sdf sdf","Description":"sd fgs df"
  }
}
--changesetresponse_b63ca946-ce66-43e6-a78f-d44a5b8f2d5c--
--batchresponse_6779b5e5-6e40-4363-9a98-5a33d062da28--
```

The only change that I made in the controller is the following (and not related to batch):

```
public class ServiceMetadatasController : EntitySetController<ServiceMetadata, int>
{
    protected override ServiceMetadata CreateEntity(ServiceMetadata entity)
    {
        return entity;
    }

    protected override int GetKey(ServiceMetadata entity)
    {
        return entity.ServiceMetadataId;
    }

    public override IQueryable<ServiceMetadata> Get()
    {
        return new List<ServiceMetadata>
               {
                   new ServiceMetadata() {ServiceName = "Service1", Description = "Desc1"},
                   new ServiceMetadata() {ServiceName = "Service2", Description = "Desc1"}

               }.AsQueryable();
    }

}
```

I hope this solves your problem, also let me know if you are generating the url for the inner request manually or if it's breezejs doing it for you, so that I can follow up and make sure it gets fixed.

Comment: That is right on the money!!
Excellent!
I still have to make Breeze using it, I hope to make it work soon.

Answer (score 4):

New answer is .. use `webApiOData` data service instead of "OData":

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ 
  dataService : 'webApiOData'
});
```

Comment: Perfect timing for your answer.  I was just about to try the hack fix posted in the edit section of OP but then I saw your answer.  he new dataService works great.  Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me. Would recommend anyone try this first, far simpler than anything else here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your issue but Microsoft's ODataModelBuilder does not implement a complete OData model.  In particular, it doesn't generate foreign key constraints.  MS is aware of this and is planning to update it in  a later release.  Until then you are better off using WCF data services to create your OData endpoints.